# MongoDb $lookup aggregation returns an empty array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I Have two mongoDB collections one is `Jobs` and the second one is `savedJob`, I want to get the job details and which job ID is present on the `savedJob` collection, But the mongoDb $lookup aggregation returns an empty array.

Firstly, I'm querying the saved job data from the `savedJob` collection, so I'm querying the saved job document through user ID method id($match) and using this pipeline to get the job details data from the `Job` collection.

The Query code is

```
const { userId } = req?.params;

  const pipeline = [
    {
      $match: {
        userId: userId,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "Jobs",
        localField: "jobId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "jobDetails",
      },
    },
  ];

  const savedJobsWithJobDetails = await saveJob.aggregate(pipeline);
  console.log(savedJobsWithJobDetails);
```

The code is working fine in the MongoDB [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sz4hKNsZtO9), But in my express server it is returning an empty array, I'm using Mongoose 6.0.1.

The saved job document looks like this:-

[image]

and the job's document looks like this:-

[image]
I checked all the model names and field names, but it's returning an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a simple typo. Change:

```
from: "Jobs"
```

to

```
from: "jobs"
```

in your `$lookup`. (Note the lowercase jobs).

You also need to convert the `jobId` from your `savejobs` schema to an `ObjectId` because at the minute you are trying to lookup a string when the target id is stored as an `ObjectId`.

This can be done with a simple `$addFields` pipeline step, leveraging the `$toObjectId` specifically to help you lookup like so:

```
const savedJobsWithJobDetails = await saveJob.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         userId: userId,
      },
   },
   {
      $addFields: { //< This new pipeline step
         jobIdToLookup: { $toObjectId: "$jobId" }
      },
   },
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "jobs",
         localField: "jobIdToLookup", //< Now use jobIdToLookup here instead
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "jobDetails",
      },
   },
   //{   
   //   $project: {
   //      jobIdToLookup: 0  //< Uncomment if you want to suppress this field from the output
   //   }
   //}
 ]).exec();
```

Comment: I already tried this way, also in lowercase or capitalized, my Model's name is "Jobs" in the Mongoose schema.

Comment: OK. Let me have another look.

Comment: Wow! It's magical working! Thank you!